# Spaceman from dying rainbows?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

*18th February 2024*

---

**Incoming Signal!**

A superluminal message has been received. It was emitted from a faraway galaxy near the black star 5 years before it became a supernova; engulfing the source of the message. In our dull, fading planet, this message could bring hope: it is your job to understand its contents. We have managed to display the data as an image on your monitor:

[image: Monitor]

We believe the alien has intelligence about human life, representing our dying rainbows in the image, but so far we can only speculate.

Team PB has recieved another message, but they are unwilling to share what they have discovered. They have hinted to us that by decrypting it first, it will make the other message faster to decrypt:

[image: Hint]

---

*Not part of the puzzle.*

I have tried to make this puzzle as original and aesthetically pleasing as I can (despite my poor gimp skills). All parts of the puzzle are used, so you should know when you are finished.

Comment: Please don't edit questions just to bump them to the top of the front page.

Comment: Sorry it was unintended

Comment: Sorry it took so long but I have updated the question to make it more doable and added a bounty because this is a good puzzle, the first bit was just to difficult

Comment: Is it significant that, for the second message, the right-most major vertical gap is wider than the other one?

Comment: @can-ned_food no

Comment: Shame the bounty got lost.  I think one of the problems — with my efforts, leastways — was that the larger image, being JPEG, had blurred colors.  A close-up of the transmission would be helpful, or maybe a re-encode with more quantization.  Nah, a cropped section is probably best.  Sorry that I was unable to mention this earlier, though.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but hope this helps:

The hex values for the 3 squares are

> 303439 644E52 565423

The three boxes underneath are all the same, and match the symbol on the computer screen.

The green box has a value of

> 415343

And the white lines are made of different colours.

The top boxes don't translate into anything from hexadecimal or ascii, however the green box with lines, the green in hexadecimal is

> ASC

Possibly hinting towards ascii.

The blob that the second arrow leads to is

> 54646D

Which in ascii is

> ".

Not sure if thats helpful